# Facebook application using php

Tags: php, facebook

I am working on this facebook application and I am following the methods documented in facebook's developer centre. I wanted to get my application to ask from the user for a certain set of permissions and I have used the exact same code given in the developer center with my app id and namespace specified. The code is given below:

```
<?php

require 'server/fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';


$app_id = 'APP_ID';

    $app_secret = 'APP_SECRET';

    $app_namespace = 'APP_NAMESPACE';

    $app_url = 'https://apps.facebook.com/' . $app_namespace . '/';

    $scope = 'email,publish_actions';


    // Init the Facebook SDK

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(

         'appId'  => $app_id,

         'secret' => $app_secret,

));

// Get the current user

$user = $facebook->getUser();

// If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Login Dialog

if (!$user) {

   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(

        'scope' => $scope,

        'redirect_uri' => $app_url,

        ));

        print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');

}

?>
```

The problem is, as I enter the url of my canvas, nothing is displayed. I want to display to the user that my app wants to access so and so things. How do I do that? I am a total newbie in this area and so your help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: _“The problem is, as I enter the url of my canvas, nothing is displayed.”_ – so you have set your app up as a canvas app on Facebook, and are trying to access it inside of Facebook? When you are browsing Facebook over HTTPS, then you need to set up an HTTPS URL for your canvas app as well, and you have to have an SSL certificate for the domain you are hosting your app on … is that the case?

Comment: Yes I am accssing it over the HTTPS protocol.And I am hosting it on heroku and I do have the SSL certificate.

Comment: Well then check with the developer tools of your browser what’s actually happening – what requests are send, how are they answered, etc.

Comment: Hey i got it working!!But only in mozilla.Do you have any idea why it didn't work in chrome?